# Passing a file location to an external process using Win32/MFC

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm trying to fulfill a client request here, and I'm not entirely sure I can actually do it. I have an MFC application that relies upon ShellExecute to open files in their appropriate viewer, which spawns multiple viewers if you try to open multiple files one after the other. If you open one .txt document, and then open another, two copies of notepad appear as expected.

The client wants us to change this functionality - Windows' functionality - to just pass file locations to any viewers that might already be opening. The first image clicked should open Image Viewer, but any other should just be opened in that existing process.

Is that kind of inter-application control/communication possible? Can I generically "pass" files to existing processes? I don't think I can. Executing a program with a file as a parameter is one thing, but passing a file to a running process is something else altogether. I'm not sure you can do that generically, I don't think that kind of functionality is anywhere in the Windows APIs.

I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible if the viewer don't support multiple open files in same instance.

in your example: notepad will launch a new version with each file, while Notepad++ (a free editor) will open in  same instance in a new tab.

Comment: Well, they're fine not opening multiple files in the same instance. If opening FileB.txt causes notepad to close FileA.txt, that's acceptable. I just don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is calling the program again with the new parameters.  If the program is written in such a way it will delegate the new parameter to the existing instance.  Notepad doesn't do this, image viewer may though.

The next thing you  can try is managing the life of the application by keeping track of the handle yourself.  You call CreateProcess, so you create and own the handle to this process.  On the next call to CreateProcess, enumerate the open windows and try to find your last handle.  If the handle is found, close it and continue with your open process.  You should only get one open application.  For the most reliable solution, put this in a separate thread and wait for the handle (as well as a new request event) to avoid any race conditions.